# MAKE text spill over into next div?

Tags: html, css, text, path

So, this is the exact opposite of the more common question (how to -prevent- text from spilling over).

I am looking for a possible way to -make- text spill over into the next div (automatically).

My site (afurnishedsoul.eu) is designed for horizontal scrolling, mainly because it contains mostly picture galleries.

I also have texts that I would like to present in this layout. If you want to picture it, imagine the divs containing the text arranged like a long row of pages from a book.

I would like the divs to behave in the following way:

They load the text (maybe, if necessary, from an external text file) and distribute it across several (the needed number of) divs.

From one page/div to the next, the text distributes evenly across the layout. All 'pages' start at the same height and end with the same lowest line, i.e. the layout is even and maintained.

Text spills over automatically from one div to the next - if you are familiar with InDesign, I want the text to behave like it's on a path.
The amount of text displayed in one div is flexible/variable, i.e. if text size is set to large in one browser, the text will distribute different from a browser with a small setting. The layout of the page overall always stays the same, but the text divides up across it automatically according to those parametres.

I know this is a tricky one, if there is a solution at all. I'd be all the more glad if somebody could help me out. The solution can be CSS or HTML preferably, but also other if necessary. Thank you all who read this, Jeff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Continuing overflowed text in a different div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400174/continuing-overflowed-text-in-a-different-div)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Tt9sw/290/

Comment: @4dgaurav oh yes, indeed. Sorry, I did not find this when I was looking for a similar post. THANK YOU for sharing the link here, to both the post and the solution - which doesn't look so bad indeed. I'll try this, unless the situation has changed in the past three years (back then, as comments say, no CSS/HTML solution).

Comment: Having learned the important word 'flow' (I'm a hobby web-programming greenhorn), I am reading now: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-multicol/ and http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn I post the links here for anyone else who might find this page looking for the same thing.

Comment: In the near future, we will have [CSS Regions](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/10/css3-regions-flow/) that will behave like text in InDesign. Not yet, however! Can i use: http://caniuse.com/#search=regions