# Continue overflowed text in div to another div in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I need to simulate book pages with text. Let's say I have a paragraph that if does not fit into the first page (div), the text overflowed, needs to continue in another one. I found this solution in jquery, but I find it quite difficult to implement in react ([Continuing overflowed text in a different div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400174/continuing-overflowed-text-in-a-different-div)) specially because of multiple renders need to simulate the text inside of a div. Can you please suggest a different approach to accomplish this? Is there maybe some npm package that does this already?

Comment: I guess you can use the Refs in React to get the DOM access and see what jQuery does with the solution that you already have and see if you can implement. Have you got the jQuery version? As long as you don't modify the DOM, that works with React.

Comment: Sounds good, but how could I simulate that without the user noticing multiple renders while calculating how much text needs to go to other div?

Comment: Ah, that's the pain with React... Good catch... Let me think about it. Wait, what about Memoization?

Comment: sounds interesting, how can I use Memoization to avoid this multiple render problems?

Comment: Found these two awesome articles: [Use `React.memo()` wisely](https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/) and [One simple trick to optimize React re-renders](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/optimize-react-re-renders). I hope these help...

Comment: Thanks! I will check